# Finding the best threshold level without a for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, threshold

Let A and B be two matrices of the same size. For a matrix M, let ht(M,t) threshold all the entries of M by t. That is All entries whose absolute value is less than t are set to 0. Suppose I want to find the optimal threshold t such that norm(ht(A,t)-B,'fro')^2 is minimized.

The only way that I can see to do this is deficient: do a for loop over the unique values of A and threshold A and setting C=ht(A,t)-B, compute sum(sum(C.*C)).

This is just too slow when A is large. I have considered sorting the elements of A and finding some efficient way to set a few entries to zero at a time, but I'm not sure this can all be done without a for loop.

Is there a way to do it?

Here's a very simple example (so simple a for loop works easily in this case):

```
B =

     0.101508820368332                         0
                     0         0.301996943246957

Set

A=B+.1*ones(2)

A =

         0.201508820368332                       0.1
                       0.1         0.401996943246957
```

Simple inspection shows that if we zero out the off-diagonal entries of A we minimize the difference between A and B. There are 3 possible threshold values, given by unique(A)=[.1,.2015,.402]. Given a potential threshold value t, we can hard threshold A by:

```
function [A_thresholded] = ht(A,t)
%
A_thresholded = A .* (abs(A)>t);
```

Comment: Could you give sample input data and list out the expected output?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute.

Comment: Instead of checking for every unique value, maybe you can employ binary search to find the threshold. I am not sure if an efficient way exists to find the optimal solution for a general case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Since norm(ht(A,t)-B,'fro')^2 is not even guaranteed to have one local minimum, what would that accomplish?

Comment: My gut feeling is that there is no simple solution other than trying to find the optimum point by iteratively searching for it. I'm not sure which algorithm to suggest, but I'd look into non-linear optimization algorithms. Posting a link to your data might give us a better idea of what techniques to try.

Comment: I think  you may want to minimize second norm of || A - t - B ||. Search for optimization techniques which can achieve this. Do not go for hard thresholding, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The form of the data in a matrix is irrelevant. You can convert them to vectors and simply compute the square-norm. In fact, you can sort the contents of `A` in increasing order (and permute `B` to preserve pairing). When you increase the threshold to include one more value in `A`, the norm only changes by that one increment. Therefore, you can find your solution in O(n log n). Hope this helps.

Comment: What is n here, the leading dimension of A?

Comment: @GregorianFunk number of elements in A. Vectorize A and B.

Comment: I think it's not really helping, since for a square p by p matrix this is O(p^2 log p), and anyway is done with a for loop (unless you are proposing something else). So I don't know that you're addressing the question.

Comment: @GregorianFunk true. But I think it will be way faster in practice. Can you show us your code so that we can compare?